# What is the Crypto++ equivalent of OpenSSL's RSA_public_decrypt?

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography, public-key-encryption, crypto++

I am implementing an authorisation system whereby a server uses OpenSSL's `RSA_private_encrypt` function (albeit indirectly) to encode a token that a client application subsequently decrypts. On the client I am using the Crypto++ library, but I can't seem to find a public API that does the equivalent of OpenSSL's `RSA_public_decrypt` function. I realise this is a slightly unusual operation from a cryptographic perspective, but I assure you this is absolutely what I want. Can anyone familiar with Crypto++ point me in the right direction in how I might replicate OpenSSL's functionality?

Comment: Regarding `RSA_private_encrypt`, encryption with the private key is not a valid cryptographic operation. Usually you want a *Signature Scheme with Recovery* (PSSR). `RSA_public_encrypt` switches gears. I believe its the discouraged [Raw RSA](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA) detailed on the Crypto++ wiki. You might also be interested in [RSA_Private_Decrypt from openssl on crypto++](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/CY_zMt_yUgY) from the Crypto++ mailing list. It has some more references to RSA pages.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, PSSR doesn't allow for any actual encryption of the data (using the private key)? I'm completely aware that the plaintext is recoverable with the public key and that this "is not a valid cryptographic operation", but that's what I want! Unless there is some other more esoteric reason this is a bad idea? I'll have a look at those links though, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you want a signature giving message recovery but if you want encryption with a private key then you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: It would probably be better to call what I want "mild obfuscation" rather than "encryption". In the end I went with an AES key followed by the payload, with the whole thing being signed by the private key. This achieves roughly the same thing, the main difference being that the attacker would no longer need to recover the public key from the client binary.